# Is it possible to convert a normal force into a vertical force of a moving object into the direction of travel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, energy-conservation, friction

I have read some questions here about normal forces applied to moving objects but I still can't find an answer to the following scenario:

So there is an object with a constant velocity and on its way the object is impacted by varying normal forces . Inside the object is a damper which brings the object back on its original path.

Can I extract energy from the damper without slowing down the object?
If not, is it even possible to convert the normal force into a force into the direction of travel to increase its velocity?
If yes, what would happen in the "black box" to make it possible in a real technical system?

My approach so far:
On one hand this system seems to be like an object with friction and it's not possible to increase speed with friction. On the other hand kinetic energy is dependent from velocity so if the impact is faster than the damper, there would be a energy difference which can be extracted.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can imagine some kind of "regenerative damping" whereby the damping mechanism would store the energy of the shocks rather than dissipate it (actuating a magnet along a coil, etc.)
2. However, since the energy of the shock is by definition a consequence of (and hence borrowed from) the kinetic energy of the body or vehicle considered, then in the best case scenario, feeding said energy back to said body would merely help to maintain its initial speed and not actually speed up the moving object.